# What's the relationship between an answer set and a model?

Tags: propositional-calculus

I'm very new to mathematical logic and recently I've encountered with the notion of ASP (answer set programming) when I'm learning classical logic.

My question is that I don't quite get the point why there comes up the notion of ASP and I don't understand the relationship between ASP and classical logic.

More specifically, I'm learning what an answer set program of some propositional signatures looks like and that an answer set (or a stable model) is an interpretation that satisfies a kind of reduction of the answer set program. To me, this seems just like the relationship between a propositional logic sentence and an interpretation (or a truth value assignment) satisfying the sentence (or making the sentence true). I believe there must be some difference between the two problems that I have missed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Did the Wikipedia article [Answer set programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming) answer your question?

Comment: I found an article talking about this problem and I put the link here [link](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10601-016-9257-7).

Comment: More or less the same; see page 311 of the paper you've linked.

Comment: A *valuation* is a function that assign a truth value to atoms. A *model* is a set of atoms: it corresponds to the set of atoms evaluated to TRUE by a valuation. The paper speaks of *interpretation* adding the conditions: *consistent* (obvious) and *complete*; also obvious: we assume that the atoms **not** evaluated to TRUE by the valuation are evaluated to FALSE.